# Rails create your own password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of creating a password reset functionality for a rails application with users and was wondering if someone could walk me through the boiler plate logic that some of the other authentication systems use.

Comment: I actually found @tight helpful so it seems that someone got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Railscast about that : [Remember Me & Reset Password](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password)

Answer (score 0):

The flow I found works well:

User clicks a 'reset password' link that goes to controller_action 'reset'
    link_to 'reset', reset_path

```
def reset
  @user = ...
  @user.temporary_password = SecureRandom(5)
  @user.password = @user.temporary_password   
  redirect_to ...
end
```

I email the @user.temporary_password. In view logic, inform a user that they need to reset their password since @user.temporary_password exists. Once they change their password, I change @user.temporary_password=nil. Done!